# Rust Cargo Releasing Unoptimized Issue

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Why my project still saying "i am unoptimized"?

[image: Why my project still saying "i am unoptimized"?]

I am doing a normal build and terminal says this build is unoptimized
And i am doing a release build and it says it optimized
but when i enter cargo check command it says unoptimized

Comment: Please modify your question so any messages are included as text. Images are a pain to read.

Comment: Ahh sorry wait a minute

Comment: @kometen I think images are fine to read, but images are not persistent. Links to images from 5 years ago are almost guaranteed to be broken.

Comment: @Finomnis Not just that; images are (a) cannot be copied (b) cost mobile users data (c) often blocked by corporate proxies (c) cannot be searched and [dozens of another reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: It would be much easier to read if you wouldn't have the warning. Create the **minimal** reproducible example.

Answer (score 3):

Because `unoptimized + debuginfo` is the default for *all* commands in cargo.

To run any command in release, please add the `--release` flag as you already did with `cargo build`:

```bash
cargo check --release
```

Answer (score -2):

For optimized builds in debug mode add these lines to your `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[profile.dev]
opt-level = 3
```

You can find more information about customizing build profiles here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-01-release-profiles.html

Comment: While correct, I think it is not related to the question